Line Integral with discontinuous functions
The line integral in polar coordinates with scalar field is defined as:
\begin{equation}
   \oint f(r,\theta) \sqrt{r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2} d\theta
\end{equation}
Imagine that we have for example a scalar field which is a rectangular function in the r-coordinates, how to find the line integral for the red curve for such function since we are integrating over $\theta$ but our recangular function is a function of $r$?

